# Rails 2 apps + RubyGems 1.8.7 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger

After upgrading RubyGems to 1.8.7 from a much older version our Rails 2 apps will no longer boot. A NoMethodError is raised with the message `undefined method 'name' for "POpen4":String`. The full stack trace follows:

```
[ pid=5996 thr=71772310 file=utils.rb:176 time=2011-08-05 16:14:59.635 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `name' for "POpen4":String) (process 5996, thread #<Thread:0x88e512c>):
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:239:in `=='
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `==='
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:217:in `matching_specs'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `find_all'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:410:in `each'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:409:in `each'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `find_all'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:216:in `matching_specs'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:238:in `to_specs'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1200:in `gem'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:57:in `add_load_paths'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in `each'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /theapplicationdir/config/environment.rb:5
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:222:in `preload_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:181:in `initialize_server'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:572:in `report_app_init_status'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:174:in `initialize_server'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    from /opt/ruby-enterprise/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.8/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Rails 3 apps are booting and running fine. Anyone have any ideas on what the error is and how we can fix it?

For some environment information - we're using Phusion Passenger 3.0.8, Nginx and REE 1.8.7.

Comment: Any hope of dragging your Rails 2.3.2 app to 2.3.12?

Comment: Are you running Rails 2 and Rails 3 application on the same server? in that case is your Rails 2 app using bundle? or RVM for both?

Comment: I think is a dependency problem u.u

Comment: @tadman that worked perfectly - I could kiss you! Do you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading your application to 2.3.12 may address some of the compatibility problems you're experiencing with a newer version of Ruby. The maintenance releases generally keep on top of these things.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to downgrade rubygems:

```
$ gem update --system 1.3.6
```